# Unity Android Build Error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I am working on 2D game in Unity.
When building for Android, Gradle build fails with following error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeReleaseResources'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  C:\Dev\Unity\Teaventures\Temp\gradleOut\native_plugins_lib\build\intermediates\packaged_res\release\drawable\app_icon_custom_coloured.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.
  C:\Dev\Unity\Teaventures\Temp\gradleOut\native_plugins_lib\build\intermediates\packaged_res\release\drawable\app_icon_custom_coloured.png: error: file failed to compile.



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
]
stdout[
> Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :native_plugins_lib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :native_plugins_lib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :native_plugins_lib:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :native_plugins_lib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :twitter_lib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :twitter_lib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :twitter_lib:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :twitter_lib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :voxelbusters_utility_lib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :voxelbusters_utility_lib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :voxelbusters_utility_lib:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :voxelbusters_utility_lib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :youtube_lib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :youtube_lib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :youtube_lib:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :youtube_lib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :native_plugins_lib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :twitter_lib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :voxelbusters_utility_lib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :youtube_lib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :native_plugins_lib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :native_plugins_lib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :native_plugins_lib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :native_plugins_lib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :twitter_lib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :twitter_lib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :twitter_lib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :twitter_lib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :voxelbusters_utility_lib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :preReleaseBuild
> Task :compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :voxelbusters_utility_lib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :voxelbusters_utility_lib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :voxelbusters_utility_lib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :youtube_lib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :youtube_lib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :youtube_lib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :youtube_lib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :mergeReleaseResources FAILED
19 actionable tasks: 18 executed, 1 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <1e5e55a0ebac44e989773ba5d6df4794>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <1e5e55a0ebac44e989773ba5d6df4794>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <1e5e55a0ebac44e989773ba5d6df4794>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <1e5e55a0ebac44e989773ba5d6df4794>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <1e5e55a0ebac44e989773ba5d6df4794>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <1e5e55a0ebac44e989773ba5d6df4794>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <1e5e55a0ebac44e989773ba5d6df4794>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <1e5e55a0ebac44e989773ba5d6df4794>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <1e5e55a0ebac44e989773ba5d6df4794>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <1e5e55a0ebac44e989773ba5d6df4794>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <1e5e55a0ebac44e989773ba5d6df4794>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <1e5e55a0ebac44e989773ba5d6df4794>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:281)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Already checked if my provided Appstore .png Image is corrupted, it isn´t.
So somehow this happens during the building Process.
Is there a way to debug this?
Am I missing something reading the Error Log?

I appreciate any hint that could help me researching for a solution.
Thank you very Much!
Korbi

EDIT: [link to corrpted file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hrUe6qjd1EvSaAxOiQ4Wzz31913rM7dT/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you sure the file is a PNG and not some other format and you have the wrong extention on it?

Comment: i exported it as PNG from Photoshop. I also tried other PNGs.

Comment: It is the Image I define in the "Project Settings -> Player Tab -> Default Icon/(Settings for Android) Icon", is it?

Comment: I added a download link of my corrpted file to the post. Maybe that helps?

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
...
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the folder the corrupted file was located:
Assets\Plugins\Android\native_plugins_lib\res\drawable

Fixing the corrupted file fixed my Issue.